# How to put two parallel flutter lists in a column

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend

I wanna put two parallel lists inside the row marked in the picture. I've tried different types of structures, but all give me problems.
Each element of the dynamic lists will have a picture and a Text.
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP12R.png)

I've been trying to put two sized box inside the row:

```
Row(children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            ),
          ])
```

After the width putting the ListView

Everything I try gives me the next error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3B0A.png)

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried using the Code Sample option {} in the text editor, and also what were the specific problems you encounter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Please refer to below code

```
 Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        ListView.builder(
                                          physics:
                                              NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                          itemCount: 15,
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                              int index) {
                                            return ListTile(
                                              leading: Icon(
                                                Icons.star_border,
                                              ),
                                              title: Text(
                                                'List $index' +
                                                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ",
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          ListView.builder(
                                            physics:
                                                NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                            shrinkWrap: true,
                                            itemCount: 15,
                                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                                int index) {
                                              return Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Icon(
                                                    Icons.star,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text("List item $index"),
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
return Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
  ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap:true,
  builder:(context,index)=> Container(),
),
  ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap:true,
  builder:(context,index)=> Container(),
),
],
);
```

Comment: Everything y try gives me the next error: